# Excel macro - Export to PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have a work book that has many macros to export various worksheets as pdfs in the same location the workbook is saved.

My issue is, if the workbook is saved in a folder on the desktop, then the PDFs are generated just fine.

When the workbook is saved on a network location, the pdfs don't generate. below is a sample of the macro:

```
Sub PDF_CStmtP()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("C Stmt - P")).Select

    pdfname = fileSaveName
    ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    fileSaveName = "Closing Statement (Purchase)"

     ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        fileSaveName _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main Menu").Activate

    MsgBox "File Saved " & " " & fileSaveName
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, `pdfname` (which you never use) will be empty/blank, since you define that before `fileSaveName` is given a value.  Also, there's no error correct?  Try changing, as a test, the `fileSaveName` to `"K:\Closing Statement (Purchase)"` (assuming `K:\ ` is a network folder). You may have to pass the full path there.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that as i have a macro enabled template that is opened, then saved as a macro enabled workbook in a different location for each file we work on. so the path would change every time. (pleasure to meet you batman)

Comment: Yeah, I know it'll change every time - it's just a quick check to see if the issue is with the file name, or something else. If you put the path directly in the filename, and it's still not saving where you expect it to, then it's something else. If it *is* saving, then it's just a matter of adding a line or two in to include the full path.

Comment: Ill give it a shot! Thanks

Comment: That worked, it saved in the correct location.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is the ChDir command, see here for an explanation: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/chdir.php

The important part of this is "The CHDIR statement lets you change the current directory on the current drive. If you need to change drives, try using the CHDRIVE statement first."

When you are trying to save to a network drive you are changing the drive letter from C:\ to whatever the network drive is mapped to, in my case it was U:\ .

The simple fix to your code is to move the Path from ChDir to just being in the filename, so your code should look like:

```
Sub PDF_CStmtP()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("C Stmt - P")).Select

pdfname = fileSaveName
'ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
fileSaveName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Closing Statement (Purchase)"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= fileSaveName, _ 
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _ 
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main Menu").Activate

MsgBox "File Saved " & " " & fileSaveName
End Sub
```

There are a few other edits you could make to clean it up, but this will solve the issue at hand.

**Based on the comment about the message box, you could change the code to this:

```
Sub PDF_CStmtP()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("C Stmt - P")).Select

pdfname = "Closing Statement (Purchase)"
'ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
fileSaveName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & pdfname

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= fileSaveName, _ 
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _ 
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main Menu").Activate

MsgBox "File Saved " & " " & pdfname
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked, and solved the issue, little clunky with the message box having the whole file path but at least it works.

Comment: ill give that a try, now that i have the solution i have a ton of macros to work on and not enough time in the day. thank you all for your help ill let you know how its goes.